# Should the Locators have awaits and is that causing flaky tests?

Tags: protractor

We're testing JS apps with protractor and sometimes we get some randomly unstable tests. Sometimes the errors are **Failed: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document**

Just a hunch but sometimes developers write the code like this

```
await element(await by.css('.pager-next')).click();
```

And sometimes like this

```
await element(by.css('.pager-next')).click();
```

Is either of these "more" correct? Is there any need for the inner await or does it make no difference? Could this be causing  stale element reference errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`await` is only useful for functions that return a `Promise`. Of the three functions in your snippet, only one of them returns a `Promise`. (You can check what each of them returns [in the Protractor api](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api)).

`ElementFinder.click()` returns a `Promise`.

`element()` returns an `ElementFinder`.

`by.css()` returns a `ProtractorLocator`.

Therefore, the only call that should have `await` on it is `click()`, which you have done correctly in your second snippet.

---

`StaleElementReferenceException` is typically caused when you keep a reference to an object that has been removed from the page, e.g. using `ElementFinder.getWebElement()`. This removal can be subtle sometimes. For example, Angular will sometimes invisibly remove an element from the DOM and quickly replace it with an identical-looking one. It's hard to tell that anything even changed, but from Webdriver's perspective, the element it had a reference to has disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

I think a better practice would be not to be write locators like that. I'd leave awaits for functions involving the element.
I would have a locator written like this:

```
const myElement = element(by.css('.pager-next'));
```

And then using async/await  in a function:

```
let clickMyElement = async function(){
   await myElement.click();
};
```

Comment: How is this better than `await element(by.css('.pager-next')).click();`?